# Problème with google load balancer, user not send to the closest instances

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, docker, google-cloud-platform

I created 6 instances in Google Cloud Plateform

- 2 in asia
- 2 in us
- 2 in europe

I have 3 groups in each zone

When i try to go to my app, i'm randomly send to one zone, no matter if i'm in Europe or an other place.

For info, i followed this documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example

I just add one zone and remove http conf.

There is no traffic on the 6 instances, only me.
All the 6 instances are available et health check are positif.

Here is my last result when i just refresh the page :

1. Asia
2. Europe
3. US
4. Europe
5. Asia
6. Asia

If you have any idea or if you need more details to help me, just ask, i will.

### Update 1

In each instance i have one nginx with one default conf :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysecure.key;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Then i have my application conf :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myapp.example.com www.myapp.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysecure.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.example.com_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.example.com.log;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    }

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
}
```

When i go to https://ip-load-balancer, it's working perfectly, always get the closest instance.

But when i try https://myapp.example.com, it's goes wrong, i can see in the log that there is some redirect.
Also when i check the log of the load balancer, he send the request to the good instance, but then i don't understand how to follow the request.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you located, and what's your latency like to the various instances?

Comment: I'm in europe, and to reach asia is like 20 secondes, for US like 7secondes.

Comment: 7-20 second latency speaks to something else majorly wrong going on.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem on the nginx. I have multi nginx stack, and for each request they received, they do a roundrobin to call the write php.

The PHP stack were on the 6 servers so it was random.

I change it to create 3 differents stack for each region.

PS: i am using docker with rancher.